# Alfresco: how to change start task name of custom workflow?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I want workflow details page to show a descriptive name for the start task instead of the form id in History table. The name attribute of userTasks works fine, but I can't get it working on my startEvent. As seen below:

```
<startEvent id="start" name="Início" activiti:initiator="initiatorUserName"
                activiti:formKey="workflowdocumentrequest:start">

<userTask id="userTask1" name="Revisão da Requisição de Documento Físico"
              activiti:assignee="${workflowdocumentrequest_destination.properties.userName}"
              activiti:formKey="workflowdocumentrequest:review">
```

[image: Name of start task not showing]

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you're developing a custom advanced workflow in Alfresco using Activiti you should check out [this Jeff Pots guide](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html).
Other than that, in order to use a customised string for your start event you should be familiar with content modeling and i18n properties files.
So for your `startEvent` you should have a specific workflow model declaring the `workflowdocumentrequest:start` type, something similar to this:

```
<type name="workflowdocumentrequest:start">
    <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
 ...
</type>
```

For that workflow content model you should have a specific i18n file, in `messages` folder called `workflowdocumentrequestWorkflow.properties`.
There you should have something like this:
`workflowdocumentrequestWorkflow_workflowmodel.type.workflowdocumentrequestWorkflow_start.title=Início`

The `workflowdocumentrequestWorkflow_workflowmodel` part is your `namespacePrefixShortname_yourWorkflowModelName` (the one you have used at the beginning of your workflow content model xml file `<model name="workflowdocumentrequestWorkflow:workflowmodel xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">`.
The `.type.` is obviously your custom type for the start event task.
The `workflowdocumentrequestWorkflow_start` is your type's name in your xml. Activiti engine and i18n file hase to be written with `_` instead of `:`.

Hope it helps.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks Alch3mi5t! I used Jeff's guide to learn about workflows but, I swear, I didn't notice this part! haha Anyway, it solved my problem. I found another approach by inserting <title/> inside my <type/> that worked as well, but yours is a better practice. Thanks once again!